# replaceAll() works once, but not twice?

Tags: java

I have this method, which works just as intended:

```
public void splitReplaceAndPrint()
{
    words = new String[200];

    String bookReplacedWithNoCommas = book.replaceAll(",", "");

    words = bookReplacedWithNoCommas.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
```

But if i try to remove the points aswell, like this... :

```
public void splitReplaceAndPrint()
{
    words = new String[200];

    String bookReplacedWithNoCommas = book.replaceAll(",", "");
    String bookReplacedWithNoPoints = bookReplacedWithNoCommas.replaceAll(".", "");

    words = bookReplacedWithNoPoints.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
```

... nothing gets printed. Why does this not work?

Comment: He you checked what exactly is contained in `bookReplacedWithNoPoints`?

Comment: what is the value of your book variable?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, its empty. But i dont understand why.

Comment: @TmTron The book string is empty from the beginning.     private String book;

Comment: @CHBR Wait, `replaceAll` uses regex doesn't it? Period is a special wildcard character meaning "everything". You need to escape the period.

Comment: `replaceAll` does _not_ mean "replace all ocurrences", but "replace all that match the regex". If you don't use a Regex, just use `replace`.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `.` mean anything so escape it.

`.` in regex will match any character so it will replace everything in string so simply you should take advantage of `replace` instead of costly regex

```
 book.replace(",", "");
```

or 
remove both `,` and `.` in single step

```
 book.replaceAll("[.,]", "");
```

`[.,]` : `[]` mean a [`character class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) which mean match both comma and dot

---

Just in case , if you want to use `replace` to remove single-single character then you can apply a chain of `replace` function as

```
String book ="The .bo..ok of ,eli..";
book.replace(",","").replace(".",""); // The book of eli
```

Comment: Or, well, just use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) instead of `replaceAll`?

Comment: Got it, thanks! :D

Comment: @tobias_k wait buddy writing takes time

Answer (score 3):

You'll  need to escape the dot, otherwise, it will match any character. This escaping is necessary because [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) treats the first argument as a regular expression. The first argument to the [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) in your case should be `\\.` not `.` i.e.

```
String bookReplacedWithNoPoints = bookReplacedWithNoCommas.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Comment: Aha, learned something new today aswell. Thanks alot!

Comment: replaceAll() take regex as input and "." is a special character in regex.